# Is it possible to create a Box within a const item?

Tags: rust

I've tried things like this:

```
const b: Box<i32> = Box::new(5);
```

Which gave me that function calls in constants are limited to struct and enum constructors.

I also tried

```
const b: Box<i32> = box 5;
```

Which gave me an error saying that I should use `Box::new` instead. Is there any way to do this? I need a box because it's in a struct and the struct requires a box.

Edit:
I know that `Box::new` is a function, and I can't use that in a `const` item. But is there another way to create a box that *is* allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not right now, not in the immediate future.

As @Paolo mentioned, the only way to initialize a `const` variable is to use a constant expression. Today, in stable, it is limited to a restricted set of operations (some integers manipulation, some casts, ...).

There is a RFC to extend the set of expressions available in constant expressions: [const fn](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0911-const-fn.md). It is about allowing functions (both free functions and methods) to be marked `const`, making them available in constant expressions.

The tracking issue is [#24111](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24111), and `const fn` can be used on nightly with the `#![feature(const_fn)]` crate attribute...

... however, at the moment, `const fn` are mostly about integral manipulations too. There is no plan that I know of to extend to arbitrary (side-effect-less) expressions, and thus it would not work for `Box::new`.

---

At the moment, you are advised to use [`lazy_static!`](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs), it will not allow the item to be `const` (it will be initialized on first use).

Comment: Does having it initialized on first use prevent it from being immutable?

Comment: @AlexKnauth: It can be immutable, but not `const`, and as far as I know cannot be stored in read-only memory. I've included a link toward the lazy-static crate, and the examples on the first page show immutable data (`static ref HASHMAP: HashMap<u32, &'static str>` for example).

Answer (score 0):

As the [const and static](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/const-and-static.html) chapter of the book says:

> Both const and static have requirements for giving them a value. They
>   may only be given a value that’s a constant expression. In other
>   words, you cannot use the result of a function call or anything
>   similarly complex or at runtime.

`Box::new()` is a function, so it falls in the scope of things you can't do to initialize a const.
You can look at [lazy-static](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/lazy-static.rs) for a way to initialize a static variable at runtime.

Comment: I know that `Box::new` is a function, and I can't use that in a `const` item. But is there another way to create a box that *is* allowed? That's what I was trying to ask.

Comment: not that I know of. But there is a way to create a static and initialize it later (with a box, if you so choose). It requires some careful unsafe code or using a macro like the one lazy-static provides.

Comment: @AlexKnauth no. Creating a `Box` requires allocating memory, which cannot be done at compile time. How would the compiler know which piece of memory would be available to be allocated at some future point in time on some arbitrary computer?

Comment: But according to the docs, const items can contain pointers as long as those are also const items that it has control over. So it seems like this should be possible, unless I'm misunderstanding?